# Capture/Filter for TLS traffic using scapy

Tags: python, ssl, scapy

I need to use scapy to capture and filter for TLS packets. I need to verify that the captured packets are TLS. I am new to scapy and the documentation is not very prolific, so if someone could help me with this, that would be great.

My logic goes as follows (rough idea):

```
from scapy.all import *
import scapy_utilities as utils
import time

scapy_filter = "tcp and src {} and dst {} and port {}".format(source_ip, destination_ip, port)

start_capture = utils.start_sniffer(scapy_filter)
time.sleep(30)
captured_packets = utils.stop_sniffer(start_capture)

verified_packets = utils.check_packets_for_tls(captured_packets)
print(f'{verified_packets}')
```

NOTE: `start_sniffer`, `stop_sniffer`, and `check_packets_for_tls` are external functions imported from a utility file

I need the results from the `print` statement to be the list of verified TLS packets

I have tried various different versions of the above logic and I have been successful except for capturing purely TLS traffic. I am unsure as to what filtering options are available for scapy to sniff TLS traffic

Currently my returned packets look like this:
[scapy_packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAny4.png)

Comment: I'm confused. What doesn't work?

Comment: It seems to only return TCP packets. I need the TLS packets. Unless all the TCP packets I am capturing are TLS...

Comment: The correct terminology is TCP packets and TLS *records*. TLS is a protocol that runs on top of TCP, so all the TLS data is inside TCP packets. TLS records need not map onto TCP packets in any convenient way, so your `check_packets_for_tls()` function will need to be stateful and rather complicated.

Comment: Ah ok. So I would need to dissect the TCP packets that I capture and filter for the TLS protocol at a deeper level basically?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. TLS records have a length field so that should help a lot.

Comment: Got it. Do you have any sources that I could look at to learn more about it?

Comment: [RFC 8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446) for TLS 1.3, probably focus on section 5. [RFC 5246](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246) for TLS 1.2 is also still around. Read that while looking at TLS data with something like Wireshark.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. I really appreciate it